# Java EWS throws NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I want to read the Outlook calendar. So I'm started first to try to connect to the server. I found http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/exchange-ews-java-api-12-1a5a1143 and want just to get the connect and try around.

I found a example and tried this:

```
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.*;
...
public void test(){     
    ExchangeService es = new ExchangeService();
    ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "Password");
}
```

It crashes by Exchange Service:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpConnectionManager
at ExchangeTest.test(ExchangeTest.java:15)
at Window.main(Window.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnectionManager
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

I tried to import a library but didn't got the correct one or the fault is something else. Can you tell me which library I need or where/how I can fix it. Thanks.

I'm using a Win7.

Comment: It looks like a missing dependency on Apache HttpClient. Make sure you have it on the classpath, or in the pom.xml if it is a Maven project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this library [The Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) and you have to add this library to the build path of your project.

Comment: I already downloaded it.(httpcomponents-client-4.3.4) and even I add all of them to the libraries (Add External JARs) it throws this NoClassDefFoundError.
There are:
commons-codec-1.6.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
fluent-hc-4.3.4.jar
httpclient-4.3.4.jar
httpclient-cache-4.3.4.jar
httpcore-4.3.2.jar
httpmime-4.3.4.jar

Comment: @Mrogath_Development try download old version from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1)

Comment: @AleksandrPodkutin, i used 
implementation group: 'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.1'   . Still i get Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.ws.http.HTTPException