# Java EWS throws NoClassDefFound SSLConnectionSocketFactory

Tags: java, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get the Java EWS 1.2 to connect to Outlook 365, but it is throwing this exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory
```

After reading this [Java EWS throws NoClassDefFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548434/java-ews-throws-noclassdeffound) I tried including these without luck:

```
httpclient-4.3.6.jar
commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about this one? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhttpclientosgi43jar.htm

Comment: Tried that, getting same error.

Comment: There is indeed an `org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.class` class contained in `httpclient-4.3.6.jar`, which you can verify by locating that jar file and running `jar tf httpclient-4.3.6.jar`.  So the `NoClassDefFoundError` indicates that that jar is not in your classpath.  How are you including it?